# How to upload image in flutter Integration Test?

Tags: flutter, testing, integration-testing, flutter-test

I have one image file that I need to upload it in Integration Test Flutter. I am not getting any help from Flutter : Integration Test documentation

I have created one folder
test_upload_files and added .png file in it and wrote the object identification of Upload Feature

then I have fetched the path of the file and tried to upload it but there are no predefined methods to upload.

I got stuck here, how to automate this Upload Functionality ?

and there is one more catch, need to enable location or camera which is from Native app, is there any solution to enable these services by default, like how we do it in Web applications using Browser Desired Capabilities?
By using flutter code can we interact with Native apps of apk and ios ?

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvBLr.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycoDG.png)

Answer (score 2):

See the [Patrol](https://github.com/leancodepl/patrol) project – it lets you interact with native permission dialogs, and basically everything, from within your Flutter integration test written in Dart.

[This issue](https://github.com/leancodepl/patrol/pull/514) demonstrates how you'd upload a single file on Android.

Disclaimer: I'm the main developer of Patrol.

Comment: Thank you Bartek Pacia, I will try this and update my observation, asap. Thanks ton :)

Comment: Is it possible from the iOS image gallery using patrol?

Comment: Yes, it is! But please ask a new question about it or ask on Patrol's GitHub